# Seananner voice-over pack

Tags: blacklight-retribution

In a game of domination a guy recently told me you can get the Seananners voice pack for free from some promotion.

Anyone know where?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to find it my self.

[This Youtube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BbtUQRWzwr0&t=0m39s), In the video the code "98WRE68" is shown in the Annotation, and in the Description is a link to the [Blacklight: Retribution redeeming page](http://blacklight.perfectworld.com/redeem), combined you get the Seanner voice pack.